# enumerating a list in R

Tags: r

In Python, you an enumerate through a list like:

```
l = ['Tom','Billy','Ron']
for c,value in enumerate(l):
    print(c,value)

## Output:
## 0 Tom
## 1 Billy
## 2 Ron
```

How can I do this in R? I need to get the index of where it is in the list and the value.

Comment: You could just do `for(i in seq_along(items)){ #code which uses i and items[i]`. Also -- are you asking about *lists* or simple *vectors* (which you would tend to use in situations where you would use lists in Python)?

Answer (score 2):

We can use `seq_along` to name the `list` and `stack` it to create a two column data.frame.  In `R`, the indexing starts from 1

```
stack(setNames(l, seq_along(l)))[2:1]
#  ind values
#1   1    Tom
#2   2  Billy
#3   3    Ron
```

---

Or with `enframe`

```
library(tibble)
library(tidyr)
enframe(l) %>%
    unnest(c(value))
```

---

Or if we need to only `print`

```
for(i in seq_along(l)) print(paste(i, l[[i]]))
#[1] "1 Tom"
#[1] "2 Billy"
#[1] "3 Ron"
```

#### data

```
l <- list('Tom', 'Billy', 'Ron')
```